# Wake a display using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wake a sleeping display using jQuery. So far, no joy. I have tried:

- trigger() and event handler such as click
- scrollTo()
- invoking the play() of an embedded (and very tiny) HTML5 <video> object

none of which actually bring the display out of sleep.

Just wondering if anyone has some bright ideas or cool methods for doing this. All help appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to listen to when the mousemoves or after a certain amount of time (or both; maybe something else)?

Comment: You can't. You can't wake a monitor from javascript code

Comment: (that should have said an embedded video object)

Comment: @fauxserious probably after a period of time e.g. setTimeout but eventually triggered by a motion detect event on a webcam picked up be an ajax call

Comment: javascript doesn't have access to the hardware to tell the monitor what to do. Just scrolling the page or making something happen on the page doesn't make the monitor wake up - you can have a desktop media player open playing a video, but if you don't get the settings right, your monitor can still go to sleep in a middle of a film. And that app probably can affect the monitor settings. Javascript in a browser OTOH is heavily sandboxed and just doesn't have the kind of local access that would be needed.

Comment: Javascript can actually prevent the screen from going to sleep but has no ability to turn it back on. [Wake Lock API](https://w3c.github.io/wake-lock/)

Comment: @ADyson Yep, I suspected as much. The only workaround I could think of is to prevent the display from sleeping and then have a masking div which fades in after a period of time, and then fades out when I want to simulate a wake event.

Comment: the flaw in that is that if you haven't got permission to wake the display, in the same way you haven't got permission to tell it not to sleep, either (apart from the mentioned Wake Lock API, which has very limited support currently). Unless you mean pre-setting this on the device in question, by hand? And any masking div will only cover the browser area, so unless the browser is fullscreen (again, beyond your control) it won't blank the entire screen.

Comment: @ADyson True, it's a Rasp Pi running Chrome in kiosk mode so full screen. I can get the Xwindow desktop to prevent sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is running in a browser, you can't. As the comments have pointed out, browser sandboxing doesn't currently give that kind of hardware access.

The closest thing is likely the [Wake Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/Wake_Lock_API). However,

> This feature is not on a current W3C standards track, but it is
>   supported on the Firefox OS platform. Although implementations may
>   change in the future and it is not supported widely across browsers,
>   it is suitable for use in code dedicated to Firefox OS apps.

If you are willing to embed java or flash plugins, they might have suitable access.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping for a jQuery only solution but appreciate that embedded plugins will have better access to hardware control.